# How to change the font style of all text layers in a single PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, text, font-management

My client has a change of heart and wanted to go from Roboto to Helvetica Neue. Is there a way to change the font style of all text layers automatically instead of the painful way one layer at a time?

I have more than 20+ screens (probably more than 1,000 layers) to go through.

I am currently using Photoshop CC 6

Comment: Could you clarify your PS version? There is CS6, CC, and CC 2014, but no "CC 6" that I know of... :)

Comment: For future projects in Photoshop CS6 or higher: Use `Window > Character styles` and/or `Window > Paragraph styles`.

Answer (score 31):

To change the font style of all text layers, you can filter all Type Layers with **Layer Filtering** option (CS6+).

You find it *on the top* of the Layers panel - [T] icon. 
Than just select all Layers that left in Layers panel and change font as you wish.

Don't forget to turn off filtering when you're done - click on the red toggle button next to filters.

[image: Changing font style of all text layers at the same time]

Comment: I can't seem to change the font. The font dialog drop down does not show when I select multiple layers. I can only see fonts drop down when I double click the [T] at the left of the text layer.

Answer (score 3):

I created script which can solve you problem. It is more handy if you have multiple fonts in single layer because traditional way replace all fonts in layer with one font.

And Photoshop built-in missing fonts dialog shows only short unusable list of fonts and can't change fonts that are already installed in file system.

1) Select all layers. Menu: Select > All layers

2) Set font pairing.

3) Run script

Download here: http://bereza.cz/ps/

Anyway now it works with Photoshop CC2015 and higher

[image: Script dialog]

Answer (score 2):

If text is the only thing which needs to be changed and it's not too deeply integrated, open up the .psd files in Adobe Illustrator and make the change there using `Type | Find Font...`

Answer (score 2):

First check all the fonts are in same format. If so take layer style or press F7. click on the top most layer and pressing shift click the last layer too. Now you have selected all layers. Then from window-->character if the same is not at on. there you have an option of choosing font. there you go. you can select whichever font style you want. It will apply to all the layer those are selected. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

One way that might work for you is to temporarily disable/uninstall the old font from your system and then use the "Replace all missing fonts" feature under the "Type" menu. It's not the prettiest way to do it, that would probably require scripting, but it should work fine in your case.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found that useful:

> Instead, link all the text layers you want to change, then select one of them and use the option bar to make the changes WHILE holding the Shift key.

[source](http://www.sitepoint.com/change-multiple-text-layers-in-photoshop/)

Answer (score 1):

Just select all your text layers you want to change and simply change their text properties like you normally would.